# Вызов внешней JS-функции в React-приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть приложение на реакте, мне с бэкенда через ajax приходит сгенерированная там js функция для сторонней библиотеки. Проблема в том, что эта функция не отрабатывает. Для тестирования максимально упростил код:

HTML:

```html
<div id="roor"></div>
<div id="external_module"></div>
```

React:

```js
                axios.request({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/_ajax/handler.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    },
                    data:qs.stringify(any_data)
                })
                .then((param) => {
                        document.querySelector('#external_module').innerHTML = param.data.content;
                });
```

и возвращаемый JS:

```html
<button id=\"clickButton\">Клик</button>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var clickHandler = function (e) {
              console.log('adsfnjdfaskjfas');
            };
            $('#clickButton').on('click', clickHandler);
        </script>
```

Как заставить возвращаемый JS работать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инъекции скрипта с кодом между тегами, этот код *не будет* выполнен, из соображений безопасности.
Это не касается программно добавляемых скриптов с атрибутом `src`.
<sup>(хотя на последние конечно действуют ограничения CSP, но это уже другая история)</sup>

Тем не менее, код в текстовом виде можно выполнить без инъекции - либо через `eval`, либо с помощью такой магии вуду:

```js
const dest = document.querySelector('#external_module'), 
      re = /<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/script>/gi; 
let code = []; 
dest.innerHTML = getContent().replace(re, (m, c) => (code.push(c), '')); 
code = code.filter(c => void (new Function(c))()); 

function getContent() {  // вместо AJAX
  return `<button id=\"clickButton\">Клик</button>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      var clickHandler = function (e) {
        console.log('Работает!');
      };
      $('#clickButton').on('click', clickHandler);
    <\/script>`;  // здесь '\' только для того чтобы сниппет не ломался
}
```

```html
<div id="external_module"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Ну и простая инъекция, для демонстрации того что она действительно не дает результата:

```js
document.querySelector('#external_module').innerHTML = getContent();

function getContent() {
  return `<button id=\"clickButton\">Клик</button>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      var clickHandler = function (e) {
        console.log('adsfnjdfaskjfas');
      };
      $('#clickButton').on('click', clickHandler);
    <\/script>`; 
}
```

```html
<div id="external_module"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, забыл про eval - он и выручил